# .htaccess file with Ember

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ember.js

So I have this Ember.js project, using node for a back-end. I am trying to add a .htaccess file so i can set exparation headers for my css,js etc. I tried putting it in the root folder of the Ember project but it does not get detected. I have a robots.txt file in the same place and it is detected fine.

I am also using Apache to redirect the domain to work with my node backend. I dont think this should be a problem as the robots.txt file is still detected this way.

Where is the best place to put the .htaccess file or is there an another soloutin to do the same thing that works with Ember?

Comment: Have you tried modifying your main apache config using a directory tag?: IE  `<Directory /usr/local/httpd/htdocs>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>`?

Comment: The path to where the .htaccess file on the server is /home/something/public_html/something/emberapp so would I change the Directory to match this path?

Comment: correct - change the path to match the root directory the ember application is being server from.